# Make the Conditional maps

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I really hope someone can help me with this question.

I want to make the Conditional maps using Python to integrate three variables. 1.the imd index 2.the major car 3. the major house.

library:
    %matplotlib inline

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import pysal as ps
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I did:

```
def map_subset(vals, db, color=None, norm=True):
    '''
    Internal function to pass to `FaceGrid` to build a single map
    ...

    Arguments
    ---------
    vals     : Series
               Values of the subplot to be mapped
    db       : GeoDataFrame
               Table with geometries
    color    : None
    '''
    ax = plt.gca()
    db.plot(color='grey', ax=ax)
    vari = vals.name
    if norm:
        db.reindex(vals.index).plot(column=vari, ax=ax, cmap='Blues', 
linewidth=0., \
                               vmin=db[vari].min(), vmax=db[vari].max())
    else:
        db.reindex(vals.index).plot(column=vari, ax=ax, cmap='Blues', 
linewidth=0.)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.axis('equal')
```

Then the main codes:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(both, row="Major car", col="Major housetype", \
                  margin_titles=True, size=5)
g.map(map_subset, "imd_score", db='imd_house_car')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The imd_house_car is the joined table from imd_house and imd_car. The Python warned:map_subset() got multiple values for argument 'db'. Please anyone let me know the flaws.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show the exact error or backtrace in the body of the question.

Comment: Also, please create a [mcve] of the issue for reproduction. Otherwise the question is likely to stay unsolved or be closed as off-topic.